# What does one call this method of grid fitting?

Tags: computer-vision

The input space has artefacts that are already in a grid-like layout:

[image]

I'd like to be able to fit/draw a grid over the artefacts so as to separate them, preferably with lines on average mid-way between neighbouring artefacts:

[image]

A bonus would be to tweak the threshold to cluster artefacts that are in closer proximity:

[image]

What does one call this method of grid fitting?

Once I know what I'm looking for, a next avenue would be which tools to use to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this has a name, but you could just apply a clustering algorithm to the X-coordinates of the red dots and separately to the Y-coordinates. For example, in Mathematica:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfhTN.png"];    
blobs = ComponentMeasurements[ColorNegate@Binarize[img], "Centroid"][[
   All, 2]];    
{meanX, meanY} = Mean /@ FindClusters[#] & /@ Transpose[blobs];
```

This will find "clusters" in the X- and Y-coordinates of the red dots:

```
Show[img, 
 Graphics[{Line[{{#, 0}, {#, 480}}] & /@ meanX, 
   Line[{{0, #}, {640, #}}] & /@ meanY}]]
```

[image]

(If you want to implement the clustering yourself, [k-means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) is a good starting point: In a nutshell, you start with random cluster centers; then assign each point to the nearest cluster center; then update the cluster centers to the mean of the values assigned to them. Repeat until convergence, split clusters if the assigned points spread too far.)

The grid you're looking for is just the lines in between these clusters:

```
inBetween = Mean /@ Partition[Sort[#], 2, 1] &;
Show[img, 
 Graphics[{Line[{{#, 0}, {#, 480}}] & /@ inBetween[meanX], 
   Line[{{0, #}, {640, #}}] & /@ inBetween[meanY]}]]
```

[image]